# Can Azure Event Grid listen to changes in Azure File Shares?

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-eventgrid

I'd like to trigger an Azure Function when a file is added to an Azure File share. I've not seen any documentation on this. Is it supported?
How would I get that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event grid does not support File share but there is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14) which says it is likely to be implemented when Azure Functions V2 goes GA (General Availability).

Currently, the following Azure services support sending events to Event Grid:

- Azure Subscriptions (management operations)
- Custom Topics
- Event Hubs
- IoT Hub
- Media Services
- Resource Groups (management operations)
- Service Bus
- Storage Blob
- Storage General-purpose v2 (GPv2)

Reference Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview

Comment: Karishma, you're answer is right but the open issue you're point at referred to Azure functions not EventGrid

Comment: I've search for a user voice entry on this subject but as I couldn't find one, I created one: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/37148959-support-file-share-storage-events