# To implement an trigger If any file is dropped in file share(Windows) ,My ADF pipeline is triggered.Pipeline 3 and 2 run after pipe 1 done

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory, fileshare

We need to start our pipeline once  a (file or multiple file) is dropped in fileshare.This trigger will run first line and once executed successfully ,needs to run second and then third sequentially.
Any of Pipeline fails the process stops  .

We have to achieve this using adf v2 and file Share .We don't want any intermediate storage location.
Please respond as soon as possible .

Answer (score 2):

Based on my knowledge it is not possible as triggers on File share is not supported in ADF, Azure function or logic app.

similar threads:
[Azure trigger function for file share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710485/azure-trigger-function-for-file-share)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114300/how-to-set-up-automatice-trigger-for-azure-file-sh.html

[Can Azure Event Grid listen to changes in Azure File Shares?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311648/can-azure-event-grid-listen-to-changes-in-azure-file-shares)

The only way would be to periodically search for the file based on scheduled trigger .

Comment: thanks .My file availability is not fixed .Can we use any triggers in ADF to manage such situations.

Comment: Hey ,you can use a schedule trigger and schedule it after every 15 min or 5 min etc as per your need.this is the only trigger which would help you in your case based on my knowledge. event trigger won't work as file share is not supported

Comment: If my files are on ADLS.Can I use any triggers which can be run sequetially?